# Function pointer size on 64 bit linux

Tags: c++, functional-programming, function-pointers

I'm writing a simpler(faster) equivalent of std/boost::function. My chief concern is simplicity and efficiency, the platform is restricted to x86-64 linux, compiled with gcc and clang.

Under the above restriction, is it fair to assume that

1. all function pointers, i.e., pointers to free function, member function (of POD, classes with virtual methods, derived classes, virtually inherited class...), functor, lambda... are all of size at most 16 bytes?
2. And what is the alignment requirement?

Comment: No, it's not safe to **assume** that. `sizeof` exists for a reason.

Comment: The answer still remains the same. **No, you should not assume anything**.

Comment: he said efficiency is important.  sometimes you have to assume things to increase efficiency, and sometimes it includes assuming things about the size of your type.

Comment: I just hope you did careful **profiling** and identified that **std::function is the bottleneck** of your application, causing significant problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For x86_64, you can safely assume that any pointer to function and/or member will not exceed the size of a pointer to a member function. For GCC this would be `sizeof(void*)`, for clang this would be `sizeof(void*)*2` (last time I checked). The alignment requirements are 16 bytes. With GCC, you can rely on `__BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__` pre-defined macro. It is absent on clang, however. The only thing that I could suggest is try not to assume, but use compile-time expression that calculates the biggest size.

**UPDATE:**

As @David has pointed out, 8 bytes might not be enough in order to dispatch a member function invocation in case of multiple and/or virtual inheritance. So `sizeof(void*)*2` applies in both cases in order to stay on a safe side.

The best way to go remains compile-time expression using `sizeof`. For example:

```
struct Foo {
};

typedef void* (Foo::*pmf)();
typedef void* (*bar)();

constexpr auto max_func_pointer_size() -> decltype(sizeof(void*)) {
    return sizeof(pmf) > sizeof(bar) ? sizeof(pmf) : sizeof(bar);
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(max_func_pointer_size() == 16, "oops!?");
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Vlad. That's really helpful. And for BIGGEST_ALIGHMENT, I think i can just do alignas(16).

Comment: Not downvoting, but there's no such thing as a "safe assumption*. There's a reason for the old saying about "assume making an ass of u and me". Once again, `sizeof` exists for a reason, and you should use it.

Comment: @KenWhite: You are right. The reason I answer is because I know what happens with both gcc and clang. I've been through this a few months back. Of course, doing nothing but assuming is no good. I'd use compile-time checks, etc. This is just how it works as of now for both  compilers in question.

Comment: @Vlad: The key to your last comment is "as of now". What happens tomorrow (or the day after, or next week or month)? This is the *exact* reason that it's not safe to *assume* anything. :-)

Comment: @RalphZhang: There were bugs with `alignas` in GCC where it was not doing what it was supposed to (sorry cannot find a link to Bugzilla right now). And it also may not work for dynamically allocated memory so you might need to resort to using `posix_memalign()` or alike.

Comment: @KenWhite: Totally agree with you, my friend. But when you cannot not hack, you hack :) and sometimes it is fun! Perhaps both this question and answer should be removed to avoid other people doing something like this, hehe.

Comment: Following on Ken's comment... you should measure again, as g++ in 64bit mode uses 16 bytes for pointer-to-member function. Note that the size of data types is part of the ABI, the [Itanium ABI](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/cxxabi-1.83.html#member-pointers) (used among others by gcc) uses `2*ptrdiff_t` for pointers to member functions. On the other hand, `sizeof` will tell you the correct size in all compilers and platforms :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: With 8 bytes of garbage, yes. You are safe and sound passing `void*` around. The only downside is a warning about PMF conversion that can be turned off with `-Wno-pmf-conversions`. If this wasn't working, I'd be in more troubles that I am now. Anyway, my point is — use sizeof! I just answered whatever was asked for, and added a note of advise... IDK why you people are so mad :)

Comment: @VladLazarenko: If by 8 bytes of garbage you mean in the general case, then we agree, but in the general case, and in particular in an scenario with multiple inheritance and/or virtual inheritance the second 8 bytes are required to correct the `this` pointer. In my case I wrote the comment because I was surprised, since I have measured the size of a pointer to member in the past and it was `2*ptrdiff_t` in gcc for virtual functions :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I don't see a reason to adjust it for multiple inheritance, but virtual inheritance is indeed a good point!